# Webform civicrm integration not respecting permissions

Tags: webform-civicrm

On my webform, I enabled 2 contacts. Contact 1 has 'Existing user' enabled and set to 'static' and default value is 'current user'. Contact 2 has 'Existing user' enabled and set to 'drop down' and default value is 'relationship to contact 1' relationship = 'child of'.

My goal is that contact 1 can go to that form and select one of his children and fill out the form. 
The form doesn't respect the filter and displays all civicrm contacts in the drop down menu.

I also tried setting default values to use filters and set the filter to contact type to= campers, I also enabled the 'Enforce Permissions'. 
The drop down still displays all civicrm contacts for contact 1 even though he only has permissions to edit his/her child.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out thanks to @Colemanw.

The relationship permissions are only for dashboard access and do not act as ACL permissions.

I installed [this extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) which transforms relationship permissions into ACL permissions. 
Now it is simple, I simply enable the 'Enforce Permission' option in the'Existing User' field and the drop down only shows the intended contacts.

Yosef

Comment: Hi @Yossi - are you having users (parents) logged in - or are you using cid and cs tokens in the URL?

Comment: I am having them log in

Comment: I'm trying to just use cid and cs for an event with guests type registration - have you ever tried that w/ permissions?

Comment: IIRC, that wont work if "enforce permissions" is enabled.

Comment: Yep - found it: https://www.drupal.org/node/2406823

Comment: user accounts it is  thanks Yossi and good evening!

Comment: Maybe take a look at @Paul Mosey comment above where he leaves the permissions disabled and loads the form in a modal/colorbox so that the URL can't be tinkered with

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question specifically, but we create this exact functionality through Views and a Webform.  The view does most of the heavy lifting.

We create a CiviCRM contact view, we use a contextual filter for the current user, add contact id for the child and render it in a table that displays the child's name and an Edit Now link to the Webform with a url of node/1?cid1=[id].

In our case, we use households as the relationship (that's why there are quite a few relationships), but it would be easier if you only had to use Child of.

On the webform, I only have one contact (the child) and it is set to static.

[image]

Comment: Cool. If someone changes the [id] in the URL would it show the contact represented by new Id? That still might be a security issue.

Comment: It would, but I would keep testing with the 2 contacts on the webform and playing with the relationship stuff on the webform component for the child.    I have it open in a colorbox so they don't actually see the url.

Comment: I want to display all contacts who Relationship≠"Paired with". The view creates a table row for every relationship, so I end up with 3 rows per contact, it does remove the row with Relationship="Paired with" but I want the whole contact to disappear. Any ideas?

Comment: Not certain I understand.

Comment: if i understand you can 'group by' in your table, and use Contact A for that field, then you should just see the names of the 3x Contact B underneath